# Python Input loop depending on number entered

Tags: python

How would I get python to ask the same question based on an input response. Say I ask the following question, how many groups would you like to configure today? The user responds with 10. I would like for python to then allow the user to enter 10 different group names so python would ask it for 10 inputs. Based on the input, I would take car of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a for loop (or, if you prefer, a list comprehension):

```
# ignoring error handling
numGroups = int(raw_input('How many groups would you like to configure today? '))

names = [raw_input('Name for group %d: '%n) for n in range(numGroups)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `raw_input` to `input` if you use python 3.x

```
n = int(raw_input('How many groups would you like to configure today? '))
for i in range(n):
    group = raw_input('Group {}: '.format(i+1))
    # Do something with group...
```

Comment: I am trying to get it to print out nice and ugly when the user enters them but it only rembers the last input

n = int(input('How many groups would you like to configure today?'))
for i in range(n):
    group = input('Group {}: '.format(i+1))

def uqdfa(money):
    return('permit ' + money)

if group == 'nice':
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.10'))
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.11'))

if group == 'ugly':
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.16'))
    print (uqdfa('233.10.10.17'))

Comment: @JoelMercado, It's hard to read a code in your comment. Put the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
resp = raw_input('How many groups would you like to configure today? ')
try:
    num = int(resp)
except ValueError as e:
    # Handle error

groups = []
for i in range(num):
    resp = raw_input('Enter group name: ')
    groups.append(resp)

# The rest (at this point, the group names will be in the list "groups")
```

...should work.  The main parts are `raw_input` and pushing the responses on to a list with `append`.  Also, make sure you handle the case where the user enters something like "Two" or just presses enter instead of a number (using the `try`/`except`).

Comment: The `# Handle error` needs to be replaced by code handling the exception.  For now, you can replace it with `pass`, but that defeats the purpose of the error handling.